# Can not connect to local Google Cloud Datastore emulator

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a new Python 3 / Flask app for the GAE App Engine Standard Environment. It works fine in the local test env and also when deployed to the cloud. As long as I do not use Datastore.

My first attempt for local test failed at line

```
datastore_client = datastore.Client()
```

when the following was written to the terminal console upon startup of

**dev_server.py:**

```
"google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application."
```

The datastore emulator is running locally on **localhost:8081**.

These are set:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=xxxxxx
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081 
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8081/datastore 
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8081 
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=xxxxxx
```

What am I missing? What kind of credentials do I need for a local (my laptop) datastore emulator and how do I set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` per:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Comment: Thanks. It still fails. I have created the service account as described on the link you provided. It is a json file, downloaded. I have set this: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/xxxxxx-b64933298f09.json". The app still fails with this message: google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. Any idea what I am still doing wrong?

Comment: Additionally, when I deploy to the cloud, datastore_client = datastore.Client() does not fail, therefore the issue seems to apply to my local environment only. I have also tried to put the json file to various places, and apply the right path in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, still the same issue. The datastore emulator is started from a separate terminal window.

Comment: `/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json` is just an example path from the docs. Do you even have such a directory?  Put the json file in the root of your project, and change the path to there.

Comment: Hi, it is there now. However, in the meantime I got closer to the solution. For some reason, my environment variables (such as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST), are not visible from within the app. I have set these in the terminal window, and can properly retrieve them by printenv. But when I start the app by "dev_appserver.py app.yaml" and do a print (os.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS") ) in it, it prints "None" to the console. Why could this be?

Comment: You can add them in your `app.yaml`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help a beginner.